# How to automatically pause a playing media on bluetooth disconnect

Tags: macos, bluetooth, headphones

I'm using Jabra Halo Smart bluetooth headphones on my MacBook Pro running OS X El Capitan 10.11. One annoying issue is that whenever I'm out of bluetooth connection range the music starts playing on internal speakers. Is there anyway to automatically pause the music on headset disconnect or change?

Comment: [AutoMute](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automute-preventing-awkward-situations/id1118136179?mt=12) is an app that addresses this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As per apple's policy , when you cross the bluetooth limit of your headset your system  will be automatically switch the audio output into the internal speakers.Mostly in platforms are like that.

But there are many third party apps like , [Breakaway](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23361/breakaway)  is a utility that will pause/resume iTunes for you whenever you unplug and/or plug in your headphones. You can now walk away from your computer for a moment without missing a beat of your favorite song, or disturbing anyone with your speakers coming on.